# mpi4py - How to avoid communication block

Tags: python, parallel-processing, communication, mpi4py

I have used MPI codes and have some basic ideas of the concepts but have never done any MPI development myself. I am starting with parallelizing some of my python codes. Here are snippets of what I'm trying to do:

```
IMPORT STUFF
...
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
status = MPI.Status()
comm.Barrier()
## CREATE EMPTY ARRAYS
if rank == 0:
   t_start=MPI.Wtime()
   tt =np.zeros(nt)
   ezp=np.zeros(nt)
   ezm=np.zeros(nt)
## NUMBER CRUNCHING LOOP
for it in range(rank,nt,comm.size):
   ...
   DO SOMETHING
   ...
## IF RANK == 0, POPULATE OWN PARTS OF ARRAY
   if rank == 0:
      tt[ it] = ltt
      ezp[it] = lezp
      ezm[it] = lezm
   if rank > 0:
   ## IF RANK != 0, SEND DATA TO PROC 0
      snddata=[it,ltt,lezp,lezm]
      comm.send(snddata, dest=0, tag=13)
   else:
#  IF RANK == 0, RECEIEVE THE DATA FROM ALL PROCS AND POPULATE
#  CORRESPONDING ARRAY ELEMENTS
      for src in range(1,comm.size):
         rcvdata=comm.recv(source=src,tag=13,status=status)
         tt[ rcvdata[0]] = rcvdata[1]
         ezp[rcvdata[0]] = rcvdata[2]
         ezm[rcvdata[0]] = rcvdata[3]
comm.Barrier()
...
WRITE THE RESULTS tt[:], ezp[:], ezm[:] TO FILE
```

I run the code with

```
mpirun -np 2 python mycode.py ARGUMENTS
```

The problem is that some times the loop decomposition does not give equal sizes of loops for the procs. E.g. if nt=21 and I use 2 procs, proc 0 loops over:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

and proc 1 loops over:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Hence for it=20, proc 0 keeps waiting to hear from proc 1 which is not doing anything. Obviously for any combination of nt and np that does not have nt%np=0, I get this problem.

What would be a good way to setting the communication in such a case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first approach that comes to mind is to send all the data in one (or maybe two) calls.

- if there is a "most possible" state, then receive the most possible.  The sender will send what it has, but it's ok to receive less than requested.
- if that's not feasible, use two messages:  one send/receive pair exchanges an int -- the number of values to expect in the next message.  Then the next message has that many values.

You did not explicitly ask this, but your code ends with "write the results to file".  Perhaps you can avoid the sending/receiving alltogether?  If all you are doing is gathering answers to rank 0, perhaps you want to look into MPI-IO approaches and have each process write directly to the file.